# Difference between Facebook Javascript SDK and Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am  new to facebook APIs. I basically want to know the difference between javascript sdk and graph API. And are there any limits for calling these APIs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ is a good way to start with.

[Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) is an SDK provided by facebook to interact with Facebook.

And [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/) is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook and it can be used with any of the available SDK's.

Better start with the following documentation available with FB and hang around there for basic understanding of how FB Apps work.

Try to google around or search in stackoverflow before posting a basic question.

Comment: Comment courtesy: @Anvesh Saxena

The limits/thresholds on the application are mentioned at Facebook Platform Policies which state them as, > If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day). Visit https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ for more details